# accessing dict/object from django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

models.py

```
class farm_model(models.Model):
  name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

views.py

```
def farms(request):
farms=farm_model.objects.all()
context = { 'farms': farms }
return render(request, 'farms.html', context)
```

farms.html

```
{% for farm in farms %}
<div style="top: {{ farm.map_top }}px; left: {{ farm.map_left }}px;">{{ farm.name }}</div>
```

How can i add map_top and map_left to farms objects from views.py ?
i've tryied

```
farms[0].map_top=80
setattr(farms[0],'map_top',80)
```

but it is not working

my second aproach was to set in views.py

```
farm_web_data={}
farm_web_data[1]={}
farm_web_data[1]['map_top']=80
```

but i don't know how to access those array from template

```
{% for farm in farms %}
<div style="top: {{ farm_web_data.{{ farm.pk }}.map_top }}px;
```

not working

any ideas ?
I don't want to store map_top in DB

Comment: How are you calculating `map_top` and `map_left`? For second farm in list what would be the value of both?

Comment: This will be fixed values. For example purpose I set only map_top for first farm, but in real views.py and template there are all values

Comment: Ok prepare a dictionary from views with farm id as key, pass it along with the context and write a [Custom Template Tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) to grab the values respective to farm in template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your first attempt is that slicing a queryset - as you do with `farms[0]` - always hits the database and gets a fresh instance. That is, the object referred to by `farms[0]` is not the same one you get when you later iterate through the queryset again.

The answer is to convert the queryset to a list straight away: then you can set attributes on the instances, and subsequent access will refer to the same instances.

```
farms = list(farm_model.objects.all())
farms[0].map_top = 80
```

Comment: Working fine! Any idea how to set it by pk ? `farms[pk].map_top=80`

Comment: You could loop through and create a dictionary mapping pk to object: `mapping = {obj.pk: obj for obj in farms}`, then set the data on `mapping[pk]` (note that this will be the same object as the one in the list, so you can still past the list rather than the dict to the template).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are trying to extend your model to include more information for your template.  You can create a data object to represent this.  It's a common pattern to create a data class that encapsulates your actual model.  You can even have methods in your data class that you can invoke in the template to do more complicated operations.

It could be something like

```
class FarmData(object):
    def __init__(self, farm, map_top, map_left):
        self.name = farm.name
        self.map_top = map_top
        self.map_left = map_left

    def some_fn(self):
        return some_output
```

and in your views.py you can do something like

```
farms = farm_model.objects.all()
farm_data_list = []
for farm in farms:
    farm_data = FarmData(farm, map_top, map_left) # I don't know how you are defining map data
    farm_data_list.append(farm_data)

context = { 'farms': farm_data_list }
```

And in your template, each `farm_data` in `farm_data_list` would have the additional properties defined in your data class.  An you can use `{{ farm_data.some_fn }}` in your template to be able to invoke methods on your data class.

While you can go down the route of using a custom tag with dictionaries, I prefer using a data class since it's a bit easier to follow down the road when you are revisiting your code.

Comment: your way is more like it should be done in correct way ..but @Daniel trick with `list(farm_model.objects.all())` is simplier. Any way thx!